# How to execute a command from Windows 10 in Apache NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I try to execute the "del" command in Apache Nifi to delete files. I'm using "ExecuteStreamCommand" in Windows 10, but it tell me that it can not found the command. Why?
I used `Command Arguments : ${absolute.path}${filename}`.

There's another way to delete files from Nifi?

Comment: Del is not an executable. It's one of the commands of windows command shell `cmd`. So to run `del` you have to start cmd like this: `cmd /c del path`

Comment: Btw, FetchFile processor could remove the source file.

Comment: About FetchFile, I don't want to pull the file in NiFi. Only delete. I try the other strategy but didn't work (the `cmd /c del path`).

Comment: `Command arguments: /c;del;${absolute.path}/${filename}`, and `Command Path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. This is used in ExecuteStreamCommand

Comment: Ok. And what's the error?

Comment: Don't recognize me the the format of the file. It's stranger. I tried with a simple GetFile, and then I use this processor.